# Custom tab under magento configuration giving 404 page?

Tags: php, magento

I am developing an extension in `Magento` in which I have added a `tab` under `general` in `system->configuration` in admin section but the problem I am having is when I am clicking on that tab it is giving me `404 error`. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Below is my `config.xml` code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<!-- turn on our module, required for install support -->
<modules>
    <Gowebbaby_Eventcalendar>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Gowebbaby_Eventcalendar>
</modules>
<frontend>
<routers>
    <eventcalendar>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Gowebbaby_Eventcalendar</module>
            <frontName>eventcalendar</frontName>
        </args>
    </eventcalendar>
</routers>
<layout>
    <updates>
        <eventcalendar>
            <file>eventcalendar.xml</file>
        </eventcalendar>
    </updates>
</layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
<routers>
    <eventcalendar>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>Gowebbaby_Eventcalendar</module>
            <frontName>eventcalendar</frontName>
        </args>
    </eventcalendar>
</routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
<menu>
    <menu2 translate="title" module="eventcalendar">
        <title>Event Calendar</title>
        <sort_order>999</sort_order>
        <children>
            <menuitem1 module="eventcalendar">
                <title>Calendar</title>
                <action>eventcalendar/adminhtml_calendar</action>
            </menuitem1>
            <menuitem2 module="eventcalendar">
                <title>Email Settings</title>
                <action>eventcalendar/adminhtml_emailsettings</action>
            </menuitem2>
        </children>
    </menu2>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <menu2 translate="title" module="eventcalendar">
                    <title>Event Calendar</title>
                    <sort_order>999</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <menuitem1>
                            <title>Calendar</title>
                        </menuitem1>
                        <menuitem2>
                            <title>Email Settings</title>
                        </menuitem2>
                    </children>
                </menu2>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</adminhtml>
<global>
<!-- turn on models -->
<models>
    <eventcalendar>
        <class>Gowebbaby_Eventcalendar_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>eventcalendar_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </eventcalendar>
    <eventcalendar_mysql4>
        <class>Gowebbaby_Eventcalendar_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
            <eventcalendar>
                <table>eventcalendar</table>
            </eventcalendar>
        </entities>
    </eventcalendar_mysql4>
</models>
<!-- turn on models -->

<!-- turn on database connections -->
<resources>
<!-- setup is needed for automatic installation -->
    <eventcalendar_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Gowebbaby_Eventcalendar</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </eventcalendar_setup>
    <eventcalendar_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </eventcalendar_write>
    <eventcalendar_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </eventcalendar_read>
</resources>

<blocks>
    <eventcalendar>
        <class>Gowebbaby_Eventcalendar_Block</class>
    </eventcalendar>
</blocks>

<helpers>
    <eventcalendar>
        <class>Gowebbaby_Eventcalendar_Helper</class>
    </eventcalendar>
</helpers>

<layout>
    <eventcalendar>
        <file>eventcalendar.xml</file>
    </eventcalendar>
</layout>
</global>
```

Below is my `system.xml` code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<sections>
    <reminder_settings translate="label" module="eventcalendar">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Event Calendar - Reminder Settings</label>
        <tab>general</tab>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <reminder_settings_option translate="label">
                <label>Event Calendar - Reminder Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <reminder_days translate="label"> <label>Send Reminder Email (No. of days)</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </reminder_days>
                </fields>
            </reminder_settings_option>
        </groups>
    </reminder_settings>
</sections>
</config>
```

Below is my `adminhtml.xml` code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <reminder_settings translate="label" module="eventcalendar">
                                    <title>Event Calendar - Reminder Settings</title>
                                </reminder_settings>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>   
</acl>
</config>
```

Can anyone please identify the issue here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you logged out and back in? ACL are loaded at login

Comment: I tried a lot, logged out and logged in several times but nothing worked :(

Comment: Did you check your PHP error log? In your `helper` do you have Data.php?